# The C# code running on Mac OS by Visual Studio 2019 for Mac is unable to write and read to/from the local Azure Storage Account Emulator

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019, azure-blob-storage, visual-studio-mac, azure-storage-emulator

I used the following two connection strings in `appsettings.json` file to read and write from/to Azure Storage Emulator installed on my Mac machine:

```
"ConnectionString":"UseDevelopmentStorage=true"
```

And

```
"ConnectionString":"DefaultEndpointsProtocol=http;AccountName=devstoreaccount1;
AccountKey=Eby8vdM02xNOcqFlqUwJPLlmEtlCDXJ1OUzFT50uSRZ6IFsuFq2UVErCz4I6tq/K1SZFPTOtr/KBHBeksoGMGw==;
BlobEndpoint=http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1;
QueueEndpoint=http://127.0.0.1:10001/devstoreaccount1;"
```

As a background, I installed Visual Studio 2019 for Mac on a fresh Mac machine. I guess Visual Studio 2019 for Mac must already have been shipped with the emulator. The Mac's operating system is macOS Catalina Version 10.15.6.

The problem that I am facing is that I am totally unable to have blobs written to, or read from the emulator and I keep getting **connection refused** error message. This issue keeps happening despite Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer installed on the Mac machine communicates with the emulator successfully, displays all blobs, writes and reads to/from the storage.

What is missing in my connection string configuration or what else I'm supposed to do on my Mac machine to have the C# code read and write from/to the storage emulator.

Comment: Wild guess: Firewall rules.

Comment: Is the storage emulator definitely running? What do you get when you run this at the command line: `azurestorageemulator status`? You may need to run this from the correct folder, e.g. `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\Storage Emulator` but the Mac version.

Comment: Neither firewall issue nor nothing else. Bottom line as I already said Azure Storage Explorer can perfectly communicate with the emulator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Azure Storage Emulator only works on Windows and is being deprecated. Other platforms use [Azurite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azurite), but the integration for it with Visual Studio is incomplete, so you have to run it manually:

https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/1343#issuecomment-678536378

This was all found with 5 minutes of consulting MSDN and using Google.

Comment: There's one catch though. Running Azurite through VS Code did not work and I had to use npm to install and run it.